# How to add Windows Authentication to a WCF application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am currently working on a WCF project in C#. I am quite new to the whole .NET area as I am usually doing Java, so please allow me a simple question:

How can I make my application ask for credentials (HTTP Digest/Basic) that uses Windows Password? I tried googling a lot but many information are misleading.

This his how my web.config currently looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true">
        </standardEndpoint>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx

Scroll down to the XML snippets.

Note the security mode in the binding setup:

```
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
```